# Meteor track mode of login with mixpanel(fb or google or email password)

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, mixpanel

I would like to track what mode of login do users sign-in to my website (facebook, google, email or password). I have installed mixpanel and not able to get the mode of login.

If there are other ways, those ways are welcome too.

Below is the code I have tried so as to track the login

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(user) {
  var u = user.user;
  if(u) {
    mixpanel.track(u)
  }
});
```

I am new to meteor and mixpanel stuff, not able to figure out the logic

error  I am facing is "mixpanel is not defined" on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You should add mixpanel to client side only. And you should add your [Accounts.onLogin](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) listener in client side.

Comment: As far as  I understand I want to track it only on server side.